# Green formula, Maxwell

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Have we got a similar Green identity with the following, $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, $E \in H(curl, \Omega)$, $\Phi$ test function smooth enough and scalar,
$$
\int_\Omega curl(E)\Phi d\Omega \overset{?}{=} ...
$$
Moreover, I'd like to know if the change of coordinate system impacts on Green formula ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: $ \int_\Omega \space ( \phi \nabla \times \mathbf{E} - \mathbf{E} \times \nabla \phi ) \space dV = \int_\Omega \nabla \times (\phi \mathbf{E}) \space dV = \int_{\partial\Omega} d \mathbf{S} \times (\phi \mathbf{E}) $

Answer (score 1):

For a better understanding of the space $H(\operatorname{curl},\Omega)$, I suggest you to take a look in this [book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387096191) page 257. For your second question, after knowing that there is a formula for your expression, try to apply change of variables on it and see what happens.

Comment: I have access to this book, but can you direct where one can find more details around the fact that $u\in H_0(\operatorname{curl},\Omega)$ if $v|_{\partial\Omega}\times n=0$?